# Keep Getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) for a text file for sentiment analysis?

Tags: python, text-files, valueerror

I am trying to turn this text file into a dictionary using the code below:

```
with open("/content/corpus.txt", "r") as my_corpus:
wordpoints_dict = {}
for line in my_corpus: 
  key, value = line.split('')
  wordpoints_dict[key] = value
print(wordpoints_dict)
```

It keeps returning:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8cf5e5efd882> in <module>()
      2     wordpoints_dict = {}
      3     for line in my_corpus:
----> 4       key, value = line.split('-')
      5       wordpoints_dict[key] = value
      6     print(wordpoints_dict)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

The data in the text file looks like this:

[Text Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GENKj.png)

Comment: According to the error, you're splitting on `-`, but not every line has that character in it.

Comment: you cant split them cause of your text file not every line has a ```-``` cause of this the split  dosent work and it returns only one value

Comment: Just use `line.split()`  That will just give you the words and the values and eliminate the whitespace.  I think that's what you're looking for.  Don't split at the hyphen, that probably signifies a negative value.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split a text value at ‘-‘. And unpack it to two values (key (before the dash), value (after the dash)). However, some lines in your txt file do not contain a dash so there is not two values to unpack. Try checking for blank lines as this could be a cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't match the error message.  I'm going to assume that the error message is the correct one...

Just add a little logic to handle the case where there isn't a `-` on a line.  I wouldn't be surprised if you fixed that problem and then hit the other side of that problem, where the line has more than one `-`.  If that occurs in your file, you'll have to deal with that case as well, as you'll get a "too many values to unpack" error then.  Here's your code with the added boilerplate for doing both of these things:

```
with open("/content/corpus.txt", "r") as my_corpus:
    wordpoints_dict = {}
    for line in my_corpus:
        parts = line.split('-')
        if len(parts) == 1:
            parts = (line, '')   # If no '-', use an empty second value
        elif len(parts) > 2:
            parts = parts[:2]    # If too many items from split, use the first two
        key, value = [x.strip() for x in parts]  # strip leading and trailing spaces
        wordpoints_dict[key] = value
    print(wordpoints_dict)
```